# PHP Strange Behaviour of file_exists

Tags: php

I have this for loop in php:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
      if (file_exists('./img/'.$i.'.jpg')) { 
          echo 'FILE: '.$i.'.jpg EXISTS!'; 
      } else { 
          echo 'FILE: '.$i.'.jpg NOT EXISTS!'; 
      }
}
```

I put in folder img only 1.jpg and 3.jpg so i need to get only for 1.jpg and 3.jpg file exists but i im getting for all files that does not exists or one file exists and all others does not exists...why is this function not returning correctly results?

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: What's the current output and what do you expect?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Why, what's the difference?

Comment: No need of extra quotes there. directly go for:- `if (file_exists("./img/$i.jpg")) {`

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930271/4248328)

Comment: I think he is confused the relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with the file structure and **relative path**

`./` is same as `/` gets the same folders in script running dir, If you want to go to parent dir then you need to add `../`

I have created the same program it works fine.

Running path **/var/www/html/test** and checking file folder **/var/www/html/test/img** and it works fine

```
   for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $selva = "./img/$i.jpg";
      if (file_exists($selva)) {
          echo 'FILE: '.$selva.' EXISTS!<br>';
      } else {
          echo 'FILE: '.$selva.' NOT EXISTS!<br>';
      }
   }
```

I think you trying to access outside dir from the php running dir so you need to use `../`

Else you can simply give the **absolute path**

you can get current folder by using `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Thanks i mixed './' and '../'...i added '../' and now is working fine..thanks for suggestions and pointing me out what i forget to do

Comment: Awesome mate, glad to see that you fixed the issue, Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
$dirname = "./img/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
```

It will give you only existing .jpg file

or you can use your own code without `else` condition:

```
 for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            if (file_exists('./img/'.$i.'.jpg')){ 
            echo '<br/>FILE: '.$i.'.jpg EXISTS!'; 
           }
       }
```