# PHP Using external disk drive for download files

Tags: php, apache, centos, external, litespeed

I have a problem with linking my external storage to my PHP home directory.

I'm using Litespeed web server on Linux Centos 6 and everything work normally in my user home directory.

But I want to create a load balancer between my 2 hard drives for serving better in peak times.

I use configs below in httpd.conf to creating an alias and it works well when I'm trying to download files directly like https://example.com/cdn/file.mp4

```
Alias /cdn/ "/cdn/files/"
<Directory "/cdn/files">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But if I try to use the path in php scripts for example check **file_exists** seems that I can't.

I set my home user and group in external directories.

Any idea ?!

**Update 1 :**
I tried symbolinks from home dir to external dir and still no result.

**Update 2 :** 
my simple php code :

```
<?php 
  if(file_exists('/cdn/files/file.mp4') || file_exists('/cdn/file.mp4') || file_exists('./cdn/file.mp4') || file_exists('./~cdn/file.mp4')){
    echo "yes";
  }else{
    echo "no";
  }
?>
```

result : no

Comment: Are you able to access these files manually through the console?

Comment: yeah, files are accessible and even I can download them directly with the link.

Comment: Sorry it seems that I didn't read properly. Then please share the piece of code with which you use it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is function because everything are fine when I'm using functions with main home directory path. file_exists('/cdn/files/file.mp4') or '/cdn/file.mp4'

Comment: Well when you are able to access the remotely stored files your conf might work well. So I suspect your function call making trouble.

Comment: Does the user who runs the script have permission to access the files?

Comment: yes, the user and group is same as the main home directory and also directory permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930150/file-exists-returns-false-but-the-file-does-exist

Comment: nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in php.ini open_basedir value. I must append the full path to the new disk in open_basedir value.

Also add open_basedir value in httpd.conf file like below:

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html">
   php_admin_value open_basedir /home/user/public_html/:/cdn/files
</Directory>

<VirtualHost myip:80>
   <Directory "/home/user/public_html">
      php_admin_value open_basedir /home/user/public_html/:/cdn/files
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost myip:443>
   <Directory "/home/user/public_html">
      php_admin_value open_basedir /home/user/public_html/:/cdn/files
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this be useful for someone :)