# PHP file_exists returns false, but file exists

Tags: php

I'm having troubles with file_exists, it returns false despite that file exists, or checking it with string.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$linkImageFull;
var_dump($path, file_exists($path), file_exists('/var/www/app/web/images/krzeselko-bespoke-synergy_main.jpg'));
```

gives result

```
string(36) "/var/www/app/web/images/krzeselko-bespoke-synergy_main.jpg"
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

`clearstatcache()` does not help.

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930150/file-exists-returns-false-but-the-file-does-exist, please check.

Comment: Something must be off, `/var/www/app/web/images/krzeselko-bespoke-synergy_main.jpg` is 58 characters long by my count, yet your debug output says the length of this string was 36?

Comment: This website is oldschool using some odd templating system, and file_exists is used through that template system. I've moved this part of code outside templating system and it works fine now, thank you for pointing me in right direction.