# php file_exists return null but file exist

Tags: php, yii

I have image exist and I can see it in both folder and browser but file_exists return always false. I did try 3 different paths but always return false
I did try with :

```
$backgroundImage =  '/var/www/html/hmhb/bramijpadv2/uploads/space_banner/thmbs/20220203/047c7c10-69d5-47a2-996b-d1e938e0c3df/image01.jpg';
```

return false

```
$backgroundImage =  'http://127.0.0.1/hmhb/bramijpadv2/uploads/space_banner/thmbs/20220203/047c7c10-69d5-47a2-996b-d1e938e0c3df/image01.jpg';
```

return false

```
$backgroundImage =  '/hmhb/bramijpadv2/uploads/space_banner/thmbs/20220203/047c7c10-69d5-47a2-996b-d1e938e0c3df/image01.jpg';
```

return false

I did change permission to 777 I was thinking it's the problem but getting same result false

```
protected function hasImage($backgroundImage)
    {
        if (file_exists($backgroundImage))
        {
            return 'Image exist';
        }
        else{
            return 'No Image exist';
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling `clearstatcache();` right before `file_exists`? Might be a caching issue.

Comment: @KevinY yes still not working

Comment: Does the directory exist at that location? `echo is_dir('/var/www/html/hmhb/bramijpadv2/uploads/space_banner/thmbs/20220203/047c7c10-69d5-47a2-996b-d1e938e0c3df/') ? 'directory exists' : 'directory does not exist';`

Comment: @KevinY string(15) "directory exist"

Comment: Try renaming the file to `image001.jpg` (with an extra 0) then adjust the code to have an extra 0. See if it can find it then.

Comment: @KevinY still the same I did add 2 other images a png one and another jpg but still same problem

Comment: What about `chdir('/var/www/html/hmhb/bramijpadv2/uploads/space_banner/thmbs/20220203/047c7c10-69d5-47a2-996b-d1e938e0c3df/');print_r(glob('*.jpg'));` does it list it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241775/discussion-between-kevin-y-and-im-learning).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_exists() returns false, but the file DOES exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930150/file-exists-returns-false-but-the-file-does-exist)