PHP 8 on IIS and execution context
I have PHP running on an IIS web server.
The server access some files stored on a different file server, with access restrictions on user level on the files though and returns the content back to the client over a web interface.
The system has for legacy reasons been running PHP 5.6.31, till now.
Now I have upgraded to PHP 8.3.9, but I run into the problem that the PHP service is no longer able to access the files to be returned.
On PHP8 file_exists($filename) returns false, while PHP5 exactly the same code returns true.
This file name is in the format of \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\sharename\filename.ext where the xxx are an IP address.
Switching back to old PHP restores access to the file.
I am assuming there is something I have not done correct in the php.ini file, but I am not able to figure it out. I have compared the two ini files, but not found anything standing out to me.
I have set fastcgi.impersonate = 1.
I control the PHP version through the PHP manager on the IIS Manager.
This code:
$file = trim('//FILE01/DOC');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');
$file = trim('\\\\FILE01\\DOC');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');
$file = trim('\\\\10.249.70.8\\DOC');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');
$file = trim('//10.249.70.8/DOC');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');
$file = trim('C:\PHP');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');
$file = trim('\\PHP');
echo "<br>$file:" . (file_exists($file)?'Exists':'Does not exist');

With PHP 5.6 I get this result:
//FILE01/DOC:Exists
\\FILE01\DOC:Exists
\\10.249.70.8\DOC:Exists
//10.249.70.8/DOC:Exists
C:\PHP:Exists
\PHP:Exists

PHP8.3 enabled and no other changes:
//FILE01/DOC:Does not exist
\\FILE01\DOC:Does not exist
\\10.249.70.8\DOC:Does not exist
//10.249.70.8/DOC:Does not exist
C:\PHP:Exists
\PHP:Exists


Are you sure that this is a problem with PHP itself? A file with the ending jpg is usually not served through PHP

It's probably caused by something in your setup, one of the details which you didn't mention here. You don't even provide a [mcve] or mention how specifically you're trying to access the file. Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Well, I am assuming it has to do with the configuration or setup of PHP8, since the setup is working (and has for the last years) when I switch back to PHP 5.6 (through the PHP manager on ISS manger console). Switching between the two versions seems to change PHP rights to access the files on this location, where the files are stored. I was wondering if PHP5 and PHP8 behaves differently from which context they execute, or any hidden gems in the php.ini I should know about?

Can you share the code involved? Also, did you check whether all settings are similar?

Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930150/file-exists-returns-false-but-the-file-does-exist

Just to confirm... Are we really talking about local files? Because you mention a file server and the path in the message kinda reminds a UNC style network path.

Yes, you are right, I edited the post to clarify that. The files are not local to the IIS/PHP, they are stored on a separate file share, and I do address them with \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\sharename, where the xxx are an IP address. The post @Martin refered may be relevant for this. I will do some test for that, when I get back in.

You may do better to recode your old 5.6 with PHP file_get_contents() and ensuring that PHP.ini allow_url_fopen = true

@Martin That would require setting up an additional server (HTTP or FTP), with their own cans of worms.
